# Product upgrade UI

Tags: wix, wix3.5

WiX is shipped with some UI options. I created a test project to try upgrade.

I use Mondo UI for this matter. The upgrade runs fine, the question is, the UI does not react to it as upgrade but as plain installation. I don't know if upgrade has supported UI or not and this is mainly the question:

Is it supported or am I missing something?

Comment: You have probably designed a "major upgrade." A major upgrade is a new installation so the behavior you see should be expected. If you do want the older version uninstalled and the newer version installed in the same location then you do have to author it the way you want it to work, which could include what @Nerielle answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add your own  [chain](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain) of dialogs. For example:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="20">
            ( Installed AND (PATCH OR REINSTALL ) ) OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
          </Publish>
<Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">REINSTALL OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
```

Comment: I got that part :) I was wondering if there is an out of the box option